# How to efficiently combine an array of Term in a BooleanQuery with Lucene.Net?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I need an advise on how to write an efficient query that deletes documents from a Lucene index, using a BooleanQuery (or another more efficient way) - the query should combine multiple Terms with Guid value (Delete documents by "Guid" field) and also by "Version" field..

An index may contain documents with same value in "Guid" field, but different value in "Version" field.

Below is my function:

```
private void RemoveFromIndex(string[] guids, IndexWriter writer)
        {
            var terms = guids.Select(guid => new Term("Guid", guid)).ToArray();

            if (!isGlobalIndex)
            {
                writer.DeleteDocuments(terms); //This is working perfectly
            }
            else
            {
                //Delete items but only of the corresponding version
                BooleanQuery bQ = new BooleanQuery();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(repository.versionName))
                {
                    bQ.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("Version", repository.versionName)), Occur.MUST);
                }

            //Is there a more efficient way of doing it?
            foreach (var term in terms) {
                bQ.Add(new TermQuery(term), Occur.SHOULD);
            }

                writer.DeleteDocuments(bQ);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, that's really the most efficient way to accomplish what you describe. For the 2nd part of your code (the outwards "else" clause), the Lucene query would be something like:

```
+GUID:someGuidValue version:v1 version:v2 version:v3
```

You can print the query object (or debug it) to confirm that that's really the Lucene query it creates for you. If yes, that's really the simplest way to do this.

==Update as per comment:==

First off, I'm not very sure what Lucene API you're using. I'm mostly familiar with the Java API. In the Java API you can [configure the max boolean clauses](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html#setMaxClauseCount%28int%29) on your boolean query, something like this:

```
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();
bq.setMaxClauseCount(3000);
```

This should help you avoid having to move the query inside the while loop.

Also, as far as multi-term queries are concerned, there is a base (abstract) MultiTermQuery class, and some actual implementations of it, such as : FuzzyQuery, NumericRangeQueriy, RegexQuery, etc. These are for more specialized/exotic queries involving multiple terms. For simple query conditions such as these ones, BooleanQuery works fine.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I ended up implementing it this way, though had to move the writer. DeleteDocuments(bQ) into the loop as well, in order to prevent "Too many clauses" exception.. I was hoping to get directed on some MultiTermQuery-kind of thing...